# pread/pwrite, buffers and disk cache

Tags: c, caching, filesystems

If my code does something like `fd = open("/dev/sdXY", ...)` and `pwrite(fd, ...)`/`pread(fd, ...)`, do the I/O operations skip the buffers or disk cache? Suppose **/dev/sdXY** is a unmounted, formatted disk partition (ext4, ufs, etc.).

I ask that because there is a need to grant contiguous file storage in an application I'm working on and I read that the only way to achieve it is doing something like what I described. However, I may remove the need for contiguous storage if that would lead in lost of buffers, disk cache or some other useful feature.

I'm also confused about if I would need to re-implement low level stuff since the partition would already be formatted with a file system. I read that would be the case for RAW disks/partitions. I already know it will be needed to handle which blocks are free or in use, files and folders structures, etc., I'm already working on that.

Another question: I have only seen something about buffers when reading about `fopen()`/`fread()`/`fwrite()` and C++'s file streams. Is it right that only these streams and the `f*` family of functions have some kind of buffer, unlike open/write/read/pwrite/pread/etc? Is this buffer the same as disk cache or something different?

A last one: Is HDD cache handled by its own drive or by file system (ext4, ufs, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is 'it depends'.  What's hard is characterizing what it depends on.

Simply using `open()` doesn't avoid the kernel disk buffer pool.  To do that, you need special options (`O_DIRECT`) on Linux.  However, using `open()` does avoid using hidden application buffers; you get to choose where the data is read from or written to without any intermediate copies.  By contrast, the `f*` family of functions do have a 'hidden' application buffer; the data is frequently read into an I/O buffer associated with the `FILE *` file stream, and then copied into your application buffers.

If your `/dev/sdXY` device is already formatted with a file system but you want to ensure contiguous file storage for a file, you are going to have to replicate a significant portion of the file system driver to ensure you allocate the space correctly.  It is unlikely to be a sensible use of your time or energy.  Yes, you would need to reimplement all sorts of low-level disk space management — it would be entirely non-trivial.  Further, the implementation for `ext4` would be quite different from the implementation for `ufs`, etc — so you'd really have your work cut out for you.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would only be needed to handle which blocks are bad, free or in use and files and folders structure. What more would I need to re-implement?

Comment: That's enough to keep you busy for a while, I think — it would certainly keep me busy for a while.  I'd have to study the ext4 file system to know what else there is to worry about.  _[…30 seconds of cogitation elapse…]_ However, I think it's a journalled file system, so you'll need to know how the journalling works, and how to make changes to your manually allocated file without messing up the contiguity of the allocated space.  I have serious doubts, now I think about it, that it is even possible.

Comment: There can be cache in the hard drive itself — that's a whole other bag'o'worms but one which you can ignore.  The HDD should make it appear that there is no such cache — except that it may perform better than it would if there were no such cache.  Anything written to the HDD should be safe once the write completes, even if the data is in HDD cache and not yet actually on disk.